# Changing gpfs inode online

Tags: redis, inode

One of gpfs on our server has a very low value of inode and that gpfs is being used by redis to write aof files and dump.rdb, so we are planning to increase the inode value on that server, the plan is to increase inode value online meaning the applications and redis wont stop and infra team will increase inode value, the command they have suggested is:

```
mmchfs gpfs-name –inode-limit 2.9G
```

I am worried will there be any impact on the running redis server (like data loss or AOF file corruption?) when the execute the command while redis is running or should we shutdown redis gracefully first?

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GPFS supports online inode expansion. The command you describe should not affect ongoing use of the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing to take into consideration is how much space is consumed on the filesystem, Spectrum Scale (GPFS) allocate space for inodes (even if you can fit data into inode space), a part from that, you can increase it online, if you are tight on space, I recommend you do it gradually (wait for the operation to complete it's not instantaneous).